# IZPack with Gradle

Tags: gradle, izpack

Has anyone used IZPack with Gradle? And how easy is it to use?  Any example code?

Comment: Did you try out the plugin I mentioned? If yes is there still a feature you are missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just released a first version of a [IzPack plugin for Gradle](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-izpack-plugin). Give it a shot! For more information on how to use it check the [README file](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-izpack-plugin/blob/master/README.md).

Answer (score 2):

we use lzpack in the griffon gradle build. have a look at https://github.com/breskeby/griffon/blob/GRIFFON_0.9.X/gradle/installer.gradle

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: there is now a great IzPack Gradle plugin, see the other comments.**

There is no Gradle plugin for IzPack that we know of, but [that is an item in our list of ideas for helping out](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/IZPACK/Ideas+for+helping+out!).

[IzPack](http://izpack.org/) is based on volunteer work, so feel free to help us, a Gradle plugin would definitely be a great addition!

Comment: I got a lot of very positive feedback for the [IzPack Gradle plugin](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-izpack-plugin). Looks like we can strike it off the list.